# Computing the radius of convergence of $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}k^kx^k$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, power-series

In order to compute the radius of convergence of
$$
\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}k^k x^k,
$$
I computed
$$
\lim_{k\to\infty}\left\lvert\frac{k^k}{k^{k+1}}\right\rvert=\lim_{k\to\infty}\frac{1}{k}=0.
$$

Hence, the radius of convergence is $r=0$?

Comment: That's right.${}$

Comment: I would say - the series is not convergent.

Comment: It should be $\left|\frac{k^k}{(k+1)^{k+1}}\right|$, but it doesn't change the conclusion.